# phpdocx library <ul> and <li> not working in docx file when <p> tag used in <li>

Tags: php, phpdocx

i am using phpdocx library to generate docx file from html content. it not working when `<p>` tag used in `<li>` tag. in generated docx file `<ul> <li>` format messed up.

nothing found for this problem

```php
$docx = new CreateDocx();
$docx->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$wordStyles = array('<table>' => 'LightListAccent3PHPDOCX', '<h1>' => 'Heading1PHPDOCX' , '<h2>' => 'Heading2PHPDOCX' , '<h3>' => 'Heading3PHPDOCX' , '<h4>' => 'Heading4PHPDOCX' , '<h5>' => 'Heading5PHPDOCX' , '<h6>' => 'Heading6PHPDOCX');
$docx->embedHTML($htmlContent, array('strictWordStyles' => false, 'wordStyles' => $wordStyles));
$docx->createDocxAndDownload('/tmp/'.$filename);
```

[image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qRJt.png)

Comment: You need to show the expected output, the achieved output, and your code, for anyone to be able to help you. Oh, and expand on "it not working".

Comment: and "messed up" isn't an adequate description of anything. Computer programs do something simple when you boil it down: you have some input, you do some processing, and you get a predictable output. So for us to help you, you need to provide: sample input data, the code you are using for processing, and the output you are getting. And of course also, please provide the output you were expecting instead, so we can compare. See also [ask] and how to produce a [mre] of your issue.